# Getting filetype/filesize from stream

Tags: php

I'm getting file contents from a stream with

```
$src_file = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

but I need to know the filetype and filesize of the file as well. This doesn't work:

```
$src_type = filetype("php://input");
$src_size = count($src_file);
```

I suppose I could write the file and then call filetype/filesize on that, but is there a way to get filetype and filesize from a stream or contents of a variable?

Comment: What does `filetype("php://input")` return?

Comment: `Warning: filetype(): Lstat failed for php://input` and `count($src_file)` returns `1`

Comment: `Returns the type of the file. Possible values are fifo, char, dir, block, link, file, socket and unknown.`

Comment: Thanks, so that's why it doesn't work. So how do I get filetype/mimetype and filesize in this case?

Comment: You can check the content-type header

Comment: you can use `pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)` for extension

Comment: @Musa How do I check content-type of a stream?

Comment: @DaHaKa but there is no file, just the stream. How can pathinfo work if there's no file?

Comment: @DaHaKa URL of what? It's an uploaded file from a client, sent by Ajax to the script.

Comment: @L84 I added answer also

Answer (score 2):

To get the full length of a string, use `strlen`, this *must* work.
There's no simple way to sniff the filetype of a stream, and you shouldn't try to do this.

But since you are dealing with `php://input`, likely from a `PUT` request, clients should generally set a proper mimetype in the `Content-Type` header. You can get this from `$_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']` or `$_SERVER['HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE']` depending on the sapi.

Answer (score -1):

In a stream, the 'type' of the file does not make any sense. A stream just represents an input of bits. So the `filetype` call will fail, because PHP simply cannot find the type. But `php://input` is not a file. It is the input given to php. In linux for example, it would be able to do the following:

```
ls | php file.php
```

In which case the input to PHP is not a file, but the output of another program.

Comment: So is there a way to get filetype / mime type of something that's not a file but has exact contents of a file?

Comment: It might be possible, but I think you would be better off giving the filename as argument to PHP, or send that to the input than to pipe it into your program.